# How to directly access the UI thread from the BackgroundWorker thread in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm creating a backup utility in WPF and have a **general question about threading**:

In the method **backgroundWorker.DoWork()**, the statement Message2.Text = "..." gives the error "**The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.**".

Is there no way for me to directly access the UI thread within backgroundWorker.DoWork(), i.e. change text in a XAML TextBox at that point?  Or do I need to store all display information in an **internal variable**, and then display it in **backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged()**, as I had to do with e.g. percentageFinished?

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestCopyFiles111.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1"  Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="10">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button x:Name="Button_Start" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                    Content="Start Copying" 
                    Click="Button_Start_Click" 
                    Height="25" 
                    Margin="0 0 5 0"
                    Width="200"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button_Cancel" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                    Content="Cancel" 
                    Click="Button_Cancel_Click" 
                    Height="25" 
                    Width="200"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar"
                     DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="0 10 0 0"
                    Height="23"
                     Width="405"
                     Minimum="0"
                     Maximum="100"
                     />

        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="Message" Margin="0 10 0 0"/>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="CurrentFileCopying" Margin="0 10 0 0"/>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="Message2" Margin="0 10 0 0"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**code-behind:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace TestCopyFiles111
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;

        float percentageFinished = 0;
        private int totalFilesToCopy = 0;
        int filesCopied = 0;

        string currentPathAndFileName;

        private List<CopyFileTask> copyFileTasks = new List<CopyFileTask>();
        private List<string> foldersToCreate = new List<string>();

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Button_Cancel.IsEnabled = false;
            Button_Start.IsEnabled = true;
            ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        }

        private void Button_Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button_Cancel.IsEnabled = true;
            backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            AddFilesFromFolder(@"c:\test", @"C:\test2");

            Message.Text = "Preparing to copy...";

            MakeSureAllDirectoriesExist();

            CopyAllFiles();

        }


        void AddFilesFromFolder(string sourceFolder, string destFolder)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(destFolder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder);
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string name = Path.GetFileName(file);
                string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);
                copyFileTasks.Add(new CopyFileTask(file, dest));
                totalFilesToCopy++;
            }
            string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceFolder);
            foreach (string folder in folders)
            {
                string name = Path.GetFileName(folder);
                string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);
                foldersToCreate.Add(dest);
                AddFilesFromFolder(folder, dest);
            }
        }

        void MakeSureAllDirectoriesExist()
        {
            foreach (var folderToCreate in foldersToCreate)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(folderToCreate))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderToCreate);
            }
        }

        void CopyAllFiles()
        {
            backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

            backgroundWorker.DoWork += (s, args) =>
            {
                filesCopied = 0;
                foreach (var copyFileTask in copyFileTasks)
                {
                    if (backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        args.Cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }

                    DateTime sourceFileLastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(copyFileTask.SourceFile);
                    DateTime targetFileLastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(copyFileTask.TargetFile);

                    if (sourceFileLastWriteTime != targetFileLastWriteTime)
                    {
                        Message2.Text = "dates are not the same";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Message2.Text = "dates are the same";
                    }

                    if (!File.Exists(copyFileTask.TargetFile))
                        File.Copy(copyFileTask.SourceFile, copyFileTask.TargetFile);

                    currentPathAndFileName = copyFileTask.SourceFile;

                    UpdatePercentageFinished();
                    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((int)percentageFinished);

                    filesCopied++;
                }

            };

            backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += (s, args) =>
            {
                percentageFinished = args.ProgressPercentage;
                ProgressBar.Value = percentageFinished;
                Message.Text = percentageFinished + "% finished";
                CurrentFileCopying.Text = currentPathAndFileName;
            };

            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, args) =>
            {
                Button_Start.IsEnabled = true;
                Button_Cancel.IsEnabled = false;
                ProgressBar.Value = 0;
                UpdatePercentageFinished();
                CurrentFileCopying.Text = "";

                if (percentageFinished < 100)
                {
                    Message.Text = String.Format("cancelled at {0:0}% finished", percentageFinished);
                }
                else
                {
                    Message.Text = "All files copied.";
                }
            };

            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void UpdatePercentageFinished()
        {
            percentageFinished = (filesCopied / (float)totalFilesToCopy) * 100f;
        }


        class CopyFileTask
        {
            public string SourceFile { get; set; }
            public string TargetFile { get; set; }
            public CopyFileTask(string sourceFile, string targetFile)
            {
                SourceFile = sourceFile;
                TargetFile = targetFile;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked at using Dispatcher.Invoke?

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { Button_Start.Content = i.ToString(); }));
```

Or use BeginInvoke if you want something to happen asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to continue using .ReportProgress and .ProgressChanged. Is there a particular reason this isn't sufficient?

Comment: no it just seemed redundant to copy "state of copying" to variable, then variable to XAML element, thought there might be a way to copy "state of copying" to XAML element directly

Answer (score 2):

There's no way you can directly access the UI from another thread. The only solution is to raise an event in the thread and then catch it in the UI thread.

If you don't want to use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) thread you'll need something like this to raise the event in the thread:

```
        // Final update
        if (Library_Finished != null)
        {
            Library_Finished(this, null);
        }
```

which is declared like this:

```
    public event EventHandler Library_Finished;
```

Then you'll need something like this in the UI thread to catch and process the event:

```
    private void Library_Finished(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Action action = () => FinalUpdate();
        if (Thread.CurrentThread != Dispatcher.Thread)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, action);
        }
        else
        {
            action();
        }
    }
```

But even if you use a BackgroundWorker you'll still need to implement the thread checking code before accessing the UI elements.