# Running own class on separate thread

Tags: c#

I want to run an own class in another thread, but if I do that I can't use my, for example, labels inside of an `EventHandler`, how can I avoid that?

That's how my code looks:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Ts3_Movearound
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TS3_Connector conn = new TS3_Connector();
        Thread workerThread = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            conn.runningHandle += new EventHandler(started);
            conn.stoppedHandle += new EventHandler(stopped);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //System.Threading.Thread connw = new System.Threading.Thread(conn);
            workerThread = new Thread(conn.Main);
            workerThread.Start();
        }

        public void started(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Status: Running!";
        }
        public void stopped(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Status: Stopped!";
        }
    }
}
```

And that's the error:

> *InvalidOperationExpetion in Line "label1.Text = "Status: Running!";"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only update the control via the UI thread. Use label1.Invoke() to do that:

```
label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    label1.Text = "Status: Running!";"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for this. You then use the following:

1) Before you call RunWorkerAsync you set the label to running as there are no thread issues.
2) After calling RunWorkerAsync if you set any control use:

```
            label1.Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Text = @"Status: Running!"));
```

3) Once the process has finished you can then set the label to stopped by assigning a method to the RunWorkerCompleted event. There should be no thread issues in this method as it runs on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

SO has a lot of data about it. I've found some for you:

[Can you access UI elements from another thread? (get not set)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450750/can-you-access-ui-elements-from-another-thread-get-not-set)

[How do I access GUI-Elements in another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507111/how-do-i-access-gui-elements-in-another-thread)

[How to directly access the UI thread from the BackgroundWorker thread in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775843/how-to-directly-access-the-ui-thread-from-the-backgroundworker-thread-in-wpf)